# Set proxy in yum.conf

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I am wondering, how to set proxy in yum.conf file -
I specified the proxy in yum.conf file

```
proxy=http://username:Password@10.203.190.5:80
```

Is this correct way ?

If yes , still I am getting the error at "yum update"

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found :             http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from fedora: [Errno 256] No more mirrors    to try.
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml
```

I tried with setting proxy on bash also, still getting the same error.

```
export http_proxy="http://username:Password@10.203.190.5:80"
export https_proxy="http://username:Password@10.203.190.5:80"
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already disabled the Selinux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I have it and it works

in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
proxy=http://proxy_host:proxy_port
proxy_username=proxy_username
proxy_password=proxy_password
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in Fedora 18, I found that the baseurl is not reachable.
I changed the baseurl in fedora.repo & fedora-updates.repo.

fedora.repo -

```
baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/i386/os/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/os/

baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/i386/debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/$basearch/debug/

baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Everything/source/SRPMS/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/source/SRPMS/
```

fedora-updates.repo-

```
baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/18/$basearch/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/$releasever/$basearch/

baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/18/$basearch/debug/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/$releasever/$basearch/debug/

baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/18/SRPMS/
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/$releasever/SRPMS/
```

After these changes **yum update** is working properly.

Thanks.